# How to set row id in Angular-7 data-table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-datatables

I'm using the angular 7  and I can't seem to find where you set the id for the rows (row id, not whole table id). Overall, it seems a bit odd, as it works with , rather than rows.

Looking through the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular7-data-table)
Tried standart things like using id='item.id', rowId='item.id' on random places, to see where they pop-up.

```
<data-table 
id="peopleTable" 
[title]='People' 
[items]='datas$' 
[header]="true" 
[pagination]="false" 
[indexColumn]="false" 
noDataMessage="No people">

        <data-table-column 
        [sortable]='true'
        [header]='tosHead'>
            <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item"> 
                  {{item.someValue.someOtherValue}}
            </ng-template>
        </data-table-column>

        <data-table-column
            [header]='someHead'
            [property]="'someNumber'"
            [sortable]='true'>
        </data-table-column>
...
</data-table>
```

Expected:  has a rowId property, which I can assign the item.id to
Actual: No mention of id property in documentation

Comment: Why you want rowId? If you need to display it, you can use a seperate `<data-table-column>`. Or else, if you need to perform some action like edit/delete, there is a (rowClick)="rowClick($event)"  which could give the entire row object.
rowClick(rowEvent) {
    console.log("Clicked: " + JSON.stringify(rowEvent.row.item));
  }

Comment: I tried the (rowClick) and it worked after I added it to the <data-table>. I've noticed it gets triggered when clicking anywhere on the row. I need something that I can attach to a button instead. I'd much rather get the rows via an id, that I can set to be the item's id. That way I can use the id for both element.getElementById and as information for my delete service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular7 data-table does not contain a property for row ids. So either extend the data-table to create a custom one with the property, or choose another type of data table.

It's not on the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular7-data-table),
It's not part of any of the three components, namely the table.component.ts, row.component.d.ts or the column.directive.d.ts

EDIT:

Removing an item from the angular7 data-table can be done by removing the item from the array that contains it.

Example:

example.ts

```
    var array = [item1], [item2], [item3];

...

    delete(item){
    this.array = this.array.filter(obj => obj !== item);
    }
```

example.html

```
<data-table [items]='array'>
    <data-table-column [property]='item.SomeProperty>
    </data-table-column>

    <data-table-column>
         <i class='btn btn-primary' (click)='delete(item)'>Delete</i>
    </data-table-column>
</data-table>
```